# "insert into" random number to mysql db

Tags: java, mysql

I'm creating program like parcel machine. I'm connected to mysql db.
As you can see I have field "final int orderPassword". I would like to generate it automatically by method which I put at the end of this topic.

```
    public static void post() throws Exception{
    final int parcelID = 2;
    final int clientMPNumber = 777777777;
    final int orderPassword = 1234;

    try{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Parcels.Orders (parcelID, clientMPNumber, orderPassword) VALUES ('"+parcelID+"', '"+clientMPNumber+"', '"+orderPassword+"')");

        posted.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
finally{
    System.out.println("Insert completed");
}
}
```

Below is method which I want to put instead of "final int orderPassword".

```
public static int generatePass(){
Random generator = new Random();
int orderPassword = generator.nextInt(9000)+1000;
return orderPassword;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Should the `orderPassword` be unique?

Comment: You should also use the advantage of `PreparedStatement` and set the values via the set-methods. A PreparedStatement should never be created with values in the query

Answer (score 1):

Given that your method is in the same class oder package, simply change

```
final int orderPassword = 1234;
```

to

```
final int orderPassword = generatePass();
```

Remark: for better random passwords, you could use some library like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: Thanks this is it, I'm incredibly happy right now :D

Comment: glad that helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a more secure password, a `String` password in particular.

- Create an array of `char` to contain numbers and letters (and special chars *optional*).
- Randomly get -*for example*- 6 chars from 6 random indices. (*Note, it can be any length, not necessarily 6, according to the field size in your DB*).

---

```
public static String generatePassword(int length){

    char source[] = "A0b1C2d3E4f5G6h7I8j9K0l1M2n3O4p5Q6r7S8t9U0v1W2x3Y4z5".toCharArray();

    Random generator = new Random();
    String password ="";

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        password += source[generator.nextInt(source.length)];
    }

    return password;
}
```

And to use it, you just do:

```
String orderPassword = generatePassword(6); // of length 6 for example
```

---

**Output Samples:**

```
36Ynv3
13Kvp5
4A4117
0zlSS3
vr5625
```